# Shorting down many if clauses in Python

Tags: python

I've got this code and i want to extend it to a veryhigh amount but it is veryy inefficient in the way I'm doing it... Maybe some one here knows a easy way to short it down.

```
if draw_x+draw_x1>50:
    space_x=10
if draw_x+draw_x1>500:
    space_x=100
if draw_x+draw_x1>5000:
    space_x=1000
if draw_x+draw_x1>50000:
    space_x=10000
if draw_x+draw_x1>500000:
    space_x=100000
if draw_x+draw_x1>5000000:
    space_x=1000000
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

```
space_x = 10**int(math.log10((draw_x+draw_x1)//5))
```

Comment: This requires either `python3` or `from __future__ import division` in `python2` right?

Comment: @DilithiumMatrix No. The '//' operator works fine in python 2.  `from__future__ import division` turns '/' into true division (as opposed to integer division) in python 2, so that 3/4 == .75

Answer (score 0):

You could use an `OrderedDict` for this.

```
from collections import OrderedDict

od = OrderedDict([
    (50, 10),
    (500, 100),
    (5000, 1000),
])

for border, value in od:
    if draw_x + draw_x1 > border:
        space_x = value
```

You could speed up this process quite a bit if you test for `<=` and break
after a match (or return inside a function):

```
od = OrderedDict([
    (5, 10),
    (50, 100),
    (500, 1000),
])

for border, value in od:
    if draw_x + draw_x1 <= border:
        space_x = value
        break
```

If your problem is really this mapping, you could simply use a formula to calculate the `space_x` variable:

```
import numpy as np
space_x = 10 ** np.log10((draw_x + draw_x1) // 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your mapping can not be expressed algebraically you can use [`bisect()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html#bisect.bisect_left) to do this, with more flexibility than that afforded by a formula (you do say that you want to extend your example).

```
from bisect import bisect_left

thresholds = [50, 500, 5000, 50000, 500000, 5000000]
spaces = [0, 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000]
space_x = spaces[bisect_left(thresholds, draw_x+draw_x1)]
```

Some examples:

```
>>> spaces[bisect_left(thresholds, 49)]
0
>>> spaces[bisect_left(thresholds, 50)]
0
>>> spaces[bisect_left(thresholds, 51)]
10
>>> spaces[bisect_left(thresholds, 50.01)]
10
>>> spaces[bisect_left(thresholds, 500)]
10
>>> spaces[bisect_left(thresholds, 501)]
100
>>> spaces[bisect_left(thresholds, 5000000)]
100000
>>> spaces[bisect_left(thresholds, 5000001)]
1000000
>>> spaces[bisect_left(thresholds, 123456789)]
1000000
```

Now it is easy to extend the mapping to values with no algebraic relationship. You can see another example of this use of the `bisect` module in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html#other-examples).